# I'm confused in javascript why the asyc function getProduct() doesn't link to .btnaddfrom on the combobox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble when I have installed the resource controller to display harga_produk data in the produk table, the data appears successfully but in the .btnaddfrom process it doesn't appear, please help, I lack information in javascripth.

here are the results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeXbR.png)

and this html code:

```
<tr >
           
            <th class="col-md-1" >
                 <label for="">produk</label>
               
                <select  class="form-control form-control-sm " name="id_produk" id="produk"  required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>--pilih produk--</option>
                <?php  foreach ($produk as $row) : ?>
                <option value="<?=$row['id_produk']; ?> "><?=$row['nama_produk'];?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    
            </th>
             
            <th class="col-md-1"  > 
               
                <label for="">harga</label>
                
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " name="" id="harga" value="" readonly required>
               
               
            </th>
            <th  class="col-md-1" > 
                <label for="">jumlah</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="" id="" value="" required>
            </th >
            <th  class="col-md-1" > 
                <label for="">subtotal</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="" id="" value="" readonly required>
            </th >
            <th class="col-md-1">
            <label for=""></label>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnaddfrom "><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        </th>
            </tr>
```

and this is the javascript code:

```
<script>
     $('#produk').on('change', (event) => {
        getProduk(event.target.value).then(produk => {
            $('#harga').val(produk.harga_produk);
        
        });
    });
    
    async function getProduk(id) {
        let response = await fetch('/api/tampildata/' + id)
        let data = await response.json();

        return data;
    }


    $(document).ready(function(e){
      $('.btnaddfrom').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();

        $('.fromtambah').append(`
        <tr >
           
           <th class="col-md-1" >
                <label for="">produk</label>
              
               <select  class="form-control form-control-sm " name="id_produk" id="produk"  required>
               <option value="" selected disabled>--pilih produk--</option>
               <?php  foreach ($produk as $row) : ?>
               <option value="<?=$row['id_produk']; ?> "><?=$row['nama_produk'];?></option>
                   <?php endforeach ?>
                   
           </th>
            
           <th class="col-md-1"  > 
              
               <label for="">harga</label>
               
               <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm " name="" id="harga" value="" readonly required>
              
              
           </th>
           <th  class="col-md-1" > 
               <label for="">jumlah</label>
               <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="" id="" value="" required>
           </th >
           <th  class="col-md-1" > 
               <label for="">subtotal</label>
               <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="" id="" value="" readonly required>
           </th >
           <th class="col-md-1">
           <label for=""></label>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnhapus "><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
       </th>
           </tr>
        
        `);
      });
    });

    $(document).on('click','.btnhapus',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    
       $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });

   
   

   
</script>
```

I hope that when .btnaddfrom selects the combobox, the harga input can display the harga_produk data for the product table